# How to generate a sphere and pass it to the asset loader

Tags: rust, amethyst

I found this code online which probably worked for a different version of the Amethyst Engine:

```
let mesh = data.world.exec(|loader: AssetLoaderSystemData<Mesh>| {
    loader.load_from_data(
        Shape::Sphere(32, 32).generate::<Vec<PosNormTangTex>>(None),
        (),
    )
});
```

Looks like now the `generate` method returns a `MeshBuilder` instead of the `Mesh` itself.
I could call the `.build()` method on the builder probably, but it requires two additional paramenters, one of which is the `QueueId`, that I do not have nor I know where to fetch them from.

How can I correctly adapt that code to Amethyst 0.15 version?

Comment: Did you try calling `.into()`? The following code works for me: `load_from_data(Sphere(...).generate::<(Vec<Position>, Vec<Normal>, Vec<Tangent>, Vec<TexCoord>)>(None).into(), ())`

Comment: @Kitsu yes I tried that one, not sure why it works compile-wise, but runtime crashes. I think it's weird to use conversions in this case, strange that it is allowed to compile, there should be a proper way of doing this. Not sure about the conceptual difference of `generate` and `build` as well...